# Where can I find all Linux commands?

Tags: linux, bash

Do you know where can I find all commands like dig, mount, grep, cat, etc. All those built-into bash and Ubuntu Linux?

Comment: If you counted the thousands of "commands" many users have written for themselves, the list would go out of date quickly. If you ignored them, your list would be incomplete. If you only considered your own machine, you would miss many not-yet-installed programs (things such as `dig` or `mutt` don't come pre-installed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Linux commands for bash** http://oreilly.com/linux/command-directory/

Comment: Do be careful with this, however. I'm running linux, and there many many items on this list that I don't have installed.

Answer (score 4):

I appear to be interpreting your question differently from the other posters; I feel like you're trying to get a comprehensive list of programs that can be run from the shell.

I'm going to start by saying, the [bash built-in commands](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_builtin.htm) can be found through the bash help system. This is distinct from the programs shipped with ubuntu like sed, awk, grep, etc.

Having said that, this list is almost certainly going to be useless, because of the sheer volume of commands (hundreds and hundreds and hundreds).

And THAT being said, there are a few ways to do this. You can do an `ls` in every directory in the PATH (usually /bin, /sbin, /usr/bin, /usr/sbin, /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/sbin is a fairly complete set of commands).

Or, at the bash prompt, you could just hit `TAB` a few times, and a list of all of the programs on your machine located in your PATH will scroll down; press `q` to escape out of that scrolling list.  This is nice, because it will auto-complete any name you start to type (for example, typing `mk TAB TAB TAB` will bring up a list of all commands in your PATH that start with `mk`.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to burn them into your brain, try this as your wallpaper:

[image]

(Click to zoom in)

Answer (score 0):

```
 % man <name_of_command>
```

or

```
 % info <name_of_command>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
man bash
```

will show you the bash's manual, where you'll find a list of all the bash commands too.

All the other commands (not just the command line ones, though, KDE/Gnome GUI programs are there too) usually are in `/usr/bin`, though you'll find some more in `/usr/sbin` or `/usr/local/bin`. To know what they do,

```
man command_name
```

so for example

```
man find
```

If you're looking for a specific command you can use `apropos`. It will help you find the program you need based on what it does. For example if you need a program to convert audio, try:

```
apropos audio
```

You'll get a list of all the man entries that have something to do with audio and are installed on your system.